# How to update previously published app using new expo account?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-play, app-store, expo

We have a published app in both Appstore and Playstore using Expo. Our previous developer has used his own expo account for releasing the app. The problem is that we need to update the app now using new expo account. How can we solve this issue? Any solution?

Comment: did you tried to contact the google play support?

Comment: No , I need to transfer app from previous expo account  to new expo account. so that I can update the app from my account.

Comment: You want to make expo publish or expo build(new apk)? look at https://forums.expo.io/t/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-project-to-another-user/6947

Comment: I want to expo build(new apk) for existing app but from new expo account @Oleg

Comment: Only if you can download a backup copy of the keystore by running: exp fetch:android:keystore with previous account